# Remove Indexes from json_encode output

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I've been searching this site and beating my brains out over trying to print_r a json_encode result without including the indexes. Nothing I've found has helped.

Here's the PHP/MySQL function to get data from the database:

```
public function listGuestsAll() {
    if(is_null($this->pdo)) {
        $this->msg = 'Connection Failed!';
        return [];
    } else {
        $pdo = $this->pdo;
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT user_id, name_first, name_last, email_address, user_role FROM guestList');
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll(); 
        return $result; 
    }
}
```

...and here's the print_r code:

```
print_r(json_encode($user->listGuestsAll()));
```

...and here's the output:

```
[
 {
   "user_id":"1",
   "0":"1",
   "name_first":"John",
   "1":"John",
   "name_last":"Doe",
   "2":"Doe",
   "email_address":"john@doe.com",
   "3":"john@doe.com",
   "user_role":"1",
   "4":"1"
 },
 {
   "user_id":"2",
   "0":"2",
   "name_first":"Jane",
   "1":"Jane",
   "name_last":"Doe",
   "2":"Doe",
   "email_address":"jane@doe.com",
   "3":"jane@doe.com",
   "user_role":"1",
   "4":"1"
}]
```

How do I get it to output without the repeating field indexed as 0:1, 1:John, 2:Doe, 3:john@doe, 4:1, etc?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: PS: I've tried array_values and array_filter, etc. Not sure if I'm doing it right, but I get the same output regardless.

Comment: What does this array look like before you encode it?

Comment: @El_Vanja ...

     Array ( 
 [0] => Array ( 
  [user_id] => 1 
  [0] => 1 
  [name_first] => John 
  [1] => John 
  [name_last] => Doe 
  [2] => Doe 
  [email_address] => john@doe.com 
  [3] => john@doe.com 
  [user_role] => 1 
  [4] => 1 ) 
etc., etc., etc.

Comment: Do you get these extra indices when querying the database?

Comment: @El_Vanja nope. I have other db calls to get specific items and display them, and they show up as expected. ETA: I have foreach loops to display user_id, name_first.'&nbsp;'.name_last, etc. and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You're using this to fetch the rows:

```
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

The documentation says that the default fetch mode is `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` which means the result is returned with both column names as keys and numeric keys.

You can specify a fetch mode. To fetch the row only indexed by numeric keys, use:

```
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

To fetch the row only indexed by column names, use:

```
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

You can also change the default globally so it affects all your fetches when you don't specify a fetch mode:

```
$this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

You should read:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php

Comment: That works. I added the PDO::FETCH_ASSOC and it works as expected, I also realized that my other functions had this but, for whatever reason, I forgot to add it to this specific one. Thank you, thank you, thank you!